# Python string.replace() function only replacing half of a string

Tags: python, replace

I have a long string `i` that contains the string between the `<fixtext>` tag in an XML document. I replace all of the `<` and `>` with `&lt;` and `&gt;` respectively in `i` and store it in a variable `n` When I debug and look at `n`, all instances of `<` and `>` are replaced correctly.

I then search a big block of text called `stigData` for `i` and replace it with `n`.

I know it is finding `i` because the `<` and `>` are replaced in the first half of the section but the second half is unchanged.

Is there a reason for this? How do I make sure it actually replaces the full string?

```py
fixTexts = re.findall(r"<\s*fixtext[^>]*>(.*?)</fixtext\s*", stigData, flags=re.S)

for i in fixTexts:
     n = i.replace(">", "&gt;").replace("<", "&lt;")
     stigData = stigData.replace(i, n)
```

Output Example (in `stigData`):

```
<fixtext fixref="F-66463r5_fix">Set the TRUSTWORTHY property OFF; or remove the database owner from the
                fixed server role(s); or change the database owner.

                ALTER DATABASE &lt;name&gt; SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF;
                GO

                (more words here)

                USE<database name>;

                (more words below)
</fixtext>
```

Desired Output (in `stigData`):

```
<fixtext fixref="F-66463r5_fix">Set the TRUSTWORTHY property OFF; or remove the database owner from the
                fixed server role(s); or change the database owner.

                ALTER DATABASE &lt;name&gt; SET TRUSTWORTHY OFF;
                GO

                (more words here)

                USE&lt;database name&gt;;

                (more words below)
</fixtext>
```

Thanks!

Comment: `flags=re.S | re.M`? Try `print(fixTexts)` in order to debug. The replacement could also be done from *re*.

Comment: When I ran your code, it produced the desired output.

Comment: @CristiFati I was trying to do that but I could not get the regex pattern to only select the < and > characters. I was guessing it was something like `<\s*fixtext[^>]*>([><])</fixtext\s*` but I am not good with regex so I wasn't sure what else to try.